# How to implement panel data models?

Tags: r, panel-data, hausman

I would like to implement `fixed effects` vs. `random effects` `logit` models using a `Hausman` test and `predict` the outcome variable on a new data set.

First I started with the `glm` pooled appoaach:

```
      data <- read.table("http://people.stern.nyu.edu/wgreene/Econometrics/healthcare.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
```

For prediction:

```
      library(caret)
      trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data$WORKING, p = .8,
                              list = FALSE,
                              times = 1)

      dataTrain <- data [ trainIndex,]
      dataTest  <- data [-trainIndex,]

      fit<-  glm(WORKING~WHITEC+HHNINC+AGE+AGESQ+EDUC+DOCVIS,data=dataTrain, family=binomial(link="logit"))

      prediction.working= round(predict(fit,newdata=dataTest  ,type="response"))

      # Here I would like to assess the prediction
      confusionMatrix(prediction.working,dataTest$WORKING)
```

My question is, can I adjust the `glm` in order to include `fixed effects`or `random effects` and use the `Hausman` test in order to compare the models? And is there a way to predict both models on new data?

Answer (score -1):

You can use plm() function in the plm package to build a panel data regression model which will help you include the fixed and random effect to build the model.

```
 fixed <- plm(y ~ x, data=Panel, model="within")
 random <- plm(y ~ x, data=Panel, model="random")
```

You can use the predict() function to predict the future values.

Comment: The question is about logit models with random effects (binary dependent variable in this case). You are confusing these models with the standard linear panel data models with random/fixed effects.